# Which of the Roman wars was the most important and riskiest for Rome?

Tags: ancient-rome, war

The Roman republic and later empire existed for quite some time and there was quite a few wars, but if I where to look up the most important ones, which would they be?

Understood in the way that the Roman's gambled almost everything they had on winning this war and if they had lost it, it wouldn't just have meant a humiliating defeat, it would have meant either that they would have been weakened beyond recovery and/or that the enemy would almost certainly soon have come to sack Rome itself?

So which battles would we be talking about when we are talking the most important battles in Roman history?

Comment: [10 of Rome’s Greatest Battles](https://www.historyhit.com/romes-greatest-battles/), [Top 12 of Rome’s Greatest Battles](https://www.ancienthistorylists.com/rome-history/romes-greatest-battles/), [The Most Important Battles in Ancient Roman History](https://www.ranker.com/list/most-important-ancient-rome-battles/aaron-edwards)...YMMV.

Comment: The title asks for the most important wars and the body asks for the most important battles, which do you want answered? I'm trying to decide whether to VtC because it needs clarity, or needs focus, or because it's essentially opinion-based.

Comment: Is your question about battles or about wars? E.g. the Second Punic War was certainly quite important for Rome, but the humiliating defeats of 218 to 216 (Trebia, Trasimene Lake, Cannae) turned out to be insufficient to defeat Rome.

Comment: Seems an explicit request for an opinion; demonstrates no prior research.

Answer (score 2):

It is very difficult to answer this question, because a war could have few risks at its beginning, and becomes very dangerous as long as fights occurred.

This is the case for the **Second Punic war**: when the Romans entered it (and Carthago was more involved in the process of launching the war than Rome), they thought the danger would be for Sicily and Spain: far enough from Rome. Later on however, the war became the most dangerous for Rome ever (except for the defeat against Brennus, civil wars and the Barbarians invasions that were actual defeat) because Rome was threatened of siege.

If you consider a war dangerous at its beginning, and I think this is more suited to your question because you spea of "gamble" and not about how the war actually turned out, then the **war against the Samnites** were the most dangerous because Rome was close for the combat fields and the Samnites were powerful. In fact, Rome suffered a defeat and survived only because it could negotiate an agreement.